# Only merging features can be patterned error Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I am trying to make a circular pattern of the following feature in [this Solidworks file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_BtETnmG_jqkF6HV0ngS32W1O-q3XHnA?usp=sharing).

[image]

I received the following message: 'Only merging features may be patterned. If appropriate, make a pattern of bodies instead.'

Can anyone tell me how to fix this error? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Tell me about the right most instance - that looks very odd. Does an anticlockwise pattern with only 3 instances work?

Comment: Obvious question, is your feature a merging feature?

Comment: The google drive link you shared is not a public link, FYI - so nobody can access it to help diagnose.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, the feature is meant to be a merging feature. I have changed the link so it publicly accessible. I was able to fix the error by deleting it and creating a new extruded boss using a new sketch but I do not see the difference between that sketch and the original sketch that causes this error.

Answer (score 1):

See my second comment.

Boss-Extrude3 is indeed *not* a merging feature. You can see in the screenshot below it creates a separate solid body.

[image: Non merging Boss 3]

Boss-Extrude5 *is* a merging feature, and causes the two solids it touches to merge into one body.

This is why your pattern works for Boss-Extrude5 only in the original part. It also explains why, at the end of your history tree, you didn't see the separate body required to do a pattern of bodies.

In your 'new extruded boss using a new sketch' you likely did not un-check the "Merge Result" setting. I assume you must have done this by accident, since you did not seem to understand my question when I asked if it was a merging feature, and you said yes!

[image: Merge Result Setting]

Checking this box 'fixes' your part, and allows the pattern to succeed as expected.

I should also mention there is *a lot* of bad modelling practice going on in this part, and I would strongly encourage you to go through all of the built-in tutorials, and to always fully define your sketches. A full run-down on that is outside the scope of your question however, and would work better via screenshare than on StackExchange.